# Alterar porta APACHE / TEAMVIEWER

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Estou usando o Ubuntu para desenvolvimento PHP, por isso tenho o Apache/php/MySql instalado.
Agora estou instalando o teamviewer para das suporte a clientes, mas este não consegue conectar.
Parei o serviço do Apache e tentei novamente e o Teamviewer funcionou perfeitamente, ou seja, acredito que seja um conflito de portas.

Não consegui achar como alterar as portas padrão para poder usar o apache e o teamviewer simultaneamente.

Alguém saberia como alterar a porta padrão do Apache ou do Teamviewer para resolver este conflito?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

No arquivo `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, altera a porta:

```
Listen 8079
```

Então no arquivo `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` altere a primeira linha:

```
<VirtualHost *: 8079>
```

Reinicie o apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```